# link_to from helper

Tags: ruby, link-to

Wondering how to do this.

I have a month helper and want to render a list of each month.

If you click on the month it would then pass the number value . I want to produce a list like this

```
Choose a month
January - February - March - April - May.....
```

That are links. My helper looks like this.

```
 MONTHLIST =  [
  [ "January", "1" ],
  [ "February", "2" ],
  [ "March", "3" ] 
  ].freeze
```

How do I use link_to to get the names and link be the value.  i.e #3 for march.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach:  pass the view to the helper

in your view

```
<%= your_helper(self, other_params) %>
```

.
.

in your helper

```
def your_helper(view, other_params)
    do_something_with_params
    view.raw view.link_to(.... link to params)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% monthlist.each do |month| %>

<%= link_to month[0], your_route(month[1]) %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you completely, you mean that you want to call the `link_to` method in your helper module, right?  Then the helper method, when called, will return the result of the `link_to` method to whichever view called it.

If that's what you want, I'm butting my head against a similar problem because the helper module cannot access the `link_to` method except through the `ActionView::Helpers::URLHelper` instance that was created in response to your service request.  I assume that this object can be accessed through a Rails system variable, but I am at a loss as to what that might be.  Thoughts?

For the interrim, my answer is to use the `link_to` method only within your view file.  Your helper file would look something like this:

```
module MyHelper
  def MyHelper.my_helper_method
    MONTHLIST =  [ [ "January", "1" ],  [ "February", "2" ],  [ "March", "3" ]   ].freeze
  end
end
```

Then your view file would call the helper method thus:

```
<% require '[path to helper file]' %>
<% months = MyHelper.my_helper_method %>
<% months.each do |month_name, month_num| %>
  <%= link_to(month_name, month_num) %>
<% end %>
```

(Yes, that was probably a more verbose code than you needed.  It could have been abbreviated.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative!  Here goes:

Make a Proc object out of the `link_to` method, then pass it from your view to the helper as an argument.  Here's how it will look...

Your view file:

```
<% require 'app/helpers/myhelper.rb' %>
<% proc_object = Proc.new( { |anchor_text, args| link_to(anchor_text, args) } )
<%= MyHelper.my_helper_method(proc_object) %>
```

Your helper file:

```
module MyHelper
  def my_helper_method(proc_object)
    months.each do |name, num|
      proc.call(name, :action => 'show', :id => num)
    end
  end
end
```

For the second arg in your proc.call statement, use what you'd normally use to set the url in your `link_to` method, e.g. `:controller => [x], :action => [y]`.

To recap, what you're doing is making a Proc that wraps your method, then sending that wrapped method to your helper, which will return html code for your hyperlink, which your .html.erb file will print to your html page.